# how to resize the subviews automatically for iOS6 because autoresize is removed from iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, autorelease, autoresizingmask

how to resize all the subviews inside a view automatically for iOS6 because autoresize is removed from iOS6?

Comment: In my experience autoresize is still there.  Or at least the "Autoresize Subviews" attribute in IB can muck things up if set (which it is by default).

Answer (score 2):

Technically the answer is to use autolayout, the replacement to the original autoresize feature available in previous iOS versions.

The new system, however, takes some time to get used to and to set up for all of your views and controls, so if you'd like to use the old autoresize controls, you can! It hasn't been removed, it's just that new apps and storyboards are automatically configured to use autolayout by default.

If you deselect "Use autolayout" in your storyboard files (first tab of the Utilities panel) then autolayout will be disabled and the autosizing controls will be available again.